# How do you find polynomial function of the image below using Lagrange interpolation?

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, lagrange-interpolation

Sorry for my bad english, the problem have so many missing parts that I dont even know how to start solving it (https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAdoY.jpg)

Comment: The picture is badly oriented to be pasted in.  The picture is also blurry.  If you want help, you need to provide the problem in a way people can see it.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually computed recursively through [Neville's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neville's_algorithm).